# Workflow Sending Too Many Emails

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, email

In my SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow, I have it set to send a reminder email if the condition is met. It will send the email that I have placed there, but it also sends another reminder email that doesn't appear there.

I'm not sure what is causing this. To troubleshoot, I have changed the workflow variable to make sure it wasn't accidentally being shared somewhere else.

I deleted the entire step where the email was, saved the workflow and then rebuilt it.

The only thing I can think of that would maybe cause this is because I copied and pasted when I built it, but I made sure to go back and change the fields and variables to make them unique to the condition. I'm not entirely sure that that's the guilty part, but its the only thing i can think of.

[image]

I am also having the same issue when I create new list items. It is only in the workflow once to write to the "Workflow History Test" list, but when I go to look, it has written it 2 or 3 times.

Comment: Some questions for you: 
1. Is the second (undesired) e-mail being sent the one from the workflow you originally copied from? Or is it sending the same e-mail from this workflow twice?
2. Can you share a full screengrab of your workflow so that we can see if there might be some additional action at play?

Comment: @BrendanW - Thanks for your response. 1. It appears that it is sending the email from the original copied step, but I can't be 100% sure how or why its doing that. Its a very long workflow with several parallel runs going on, so I did some copy and pasting since the steps were the same. It will send the correct email, and then send a second email (formatted exactly like the emails further down the workflow). All of these happen at the same step, so I have pinpointed down to the spot. I am editing the picture above to show you the main parent stage where this instance occurs.

Comment: It looks like the picture edit didn't work. Can you please re-upload?

Comment: Did that work? I was only able to clip what fit in my screen.

Comment: It does, but it's hard to say for sure what's going on because I still can't see all the actions you have running in parallel. My best guess is that there might be a glitch in your logic loops which is causing the step you originally copied to run in addition to the one that's sending the desired e-mail, and that this is resulting in the duplicate receipt. Try adding a workflow history log action to the step with the erroneous e-mail (the one you copied from earlier) and see if that triggers. Since you've added it post-copy, that will tell you that block of code is running.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the 'User Alerts' settings? Most lists/library items have the option to set up an alert so that when an item is added or changed that user will get an email regarding it. This setting is separate from workflow emails and may be the cause of your repeated email problem.

Comment: I have encountered this before, but disabled the alert. The extra email that I'm getting is one that I customized and that is used in the same order, just with Reviewer 2 and Reviewer 3. It's really strange!